# Is deadlock possible when locking one global object in ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, locking, deadlock

For locking I am using a single static object which is global to my application:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{        
    public static readonly object AppLock = new object();
    ...
}
```

Using it for locking in code:

```
lock(MvcApplication.AppLock)
{
    ...
}
```

Let us not consider performance impact for a moment. Can I be 100% sure that I will avoid deadlock in this case?

Comment: The definition of a deadlock is as L.B posted below.  Are you sure that's what you are safeguarding against?  If not, what situation do you need to avoid?

Comment: I want to use this technique to avoid any kind of deadlocks in my application.

Comment: Of course, given that all locks in my app use MvcApplication.AppLock object only.

Comment: I don't think you understand a deadlock then.  If you're adding a `lock` to remove deadlocks, then you don't understand that for a deadlock you need to have two `lock`s to begin with.  Or are you talking about SQL Server deadlocks, something very different?

Comment: Oh, sorry for confusion. I meant that I have more than one lock block in my web application, a lot of them, actually. I just wanted to make sure that it would not deadlock in any condition. And yes, I meant only my C# code in asp.net mvc project, not the sql deadlock.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can not create a deadlock conditon just with one lock-object(AppLock) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock . But it is possible with this kind of codes in threads

```
lock(A)
   lock(B)
       DoSomething();


lock(B)
   lock(A)
       DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's possible in ASP.NET but in winforms/wpf you can do it.

['Deadlock' with only one locked object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045938/deadlock-with-only-one-locked-object/29119536#29119536)

> Another deadlocking scenario arises when calling Dispatcher.Invoke (in
>   a WPF application) or Control.Invoke (in a Windows Forms application)
>   while in possession of a lock. If the UI happens to be running another
>   method that’s waiting on the same lock, a deadlock will happen right
>   there. This can often be fixed simply by calling BeginInvoke instead
>   of Invoke. Alternatively, you can release your lock before calling
>   Invoke, although this won't work if your caller took out the lock. We
>   explain Invoke and BeginInvoke in Rich Client Applications and Thread
>   Affinity.

source: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx