# Reproduce threading deadlock with simple C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I guess I got problems with deadlock...My program is working well but some time it get unresponsive...???.
In source code (C#)..have no lock(objet) or ReaderWriterLockSlim...
I did try to reproduce the deadlock with 2 threads using same object (List) but no success..

```
int n = 0;                      
  List<int> temp = new List<int>();
  var up = new Thread(() =>{
     for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
     n++;
     temp.Add(i);                   
}
});

var down = new Thread(() => {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        n--;
         try{
           temp.Remove(i);
         }catch {
           Console.WriteLine("No item {0} to remove", i);
         }
        }
});

up.Start();
down.Start();
down.Join();
up.Join();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",temp));
```

The snipe code above still works without deadlock..???
Could someone help me to reproduce the deadlock with 2 threads using same variable without lock(object) or System lock...

Thank in Advance

Comment: What code _does_ have the problem? Are you sure it's a threading deadlock, and not something else causing unresponsiveness?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with your production code?

Comment: Since you have no lock in this code, so there can not be a deadlock problem, but weird behavior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064296/is-deadlock-possible-when-locking-one-global-object-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: when its stuck, break in with the debugger and see where the threads are

Comment: Use WinDbg and attached to the process when it is hung to figure out why. Also, the code you posted isn't thread-safe. The `Add` or `Remove` calls might throw an exception, corrupt the data structure, or even tear a whole in spacetime. Either way eventually something spectacular will occur.

Comment: Deal all. Actually I want to reproduce a deadlock to get understanding how it happens. Because my program using opensource framework is written in multithreading pattern so I guess problem come from threads are using same resource...
I did try snipe code above with and expect that may cause a deadlocking but nothing happen..
So I need someone help me to reproduce this problem without lock or system lock..
@Brian Gideon..thank for your suggestion..Actually the snipe code still working well so I have no chance to see in WinDbg

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel. No, I can't reproduce the problem. Sometime system hang up (1 or 2 times perday).

Comment: @Tim S I guess..., because other part of code is very simple and I don't believe it may cause problem.

Comment: I'll suggest you to try simulating the problem with your program in debug mode. If simulated then pause the debugger and open Debug->Windows->Threads to inspect all thread's execution point you can easily find where main thread is blocked on which resource and which thread is causing the deadlock to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List` is not thread-safe so this will be the cause of your problem. You should create a thread-safe solution (using `lock` or with thread-safe collections) and not focus on recreating the deadlock. What will that tell you?

Comment: Thank @meilke..I guess problem come from non thread-safe-mode. But I need to reproduce the system hang before apply any solution..And I what I need now is looking for snipe code can let system hang up. (without lock object or system lock).

Comment: @hoanganh17b, I agree, it is important to reproduce problems so that when we do fix issues, we are confident that we are addressing the actual problem. I found this blog post interesting: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/12/21/high-cpu-in-net-app-using-a-static-generic-dictionary.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Normally a deadlock occurs when using locks or synchronization.

Most common deadlocks are updateing the Gui from a thread. Like:

```
Thread thread = new Thread( () => 
{ 
    Invoke(new Action(() => 
    {
        Label1.Text = "something";
    }));
});

thread.Start();

// this join will prevent the messageloop from running, but the invoke waits on the messageloop to execute it's action.
thread.Join();
```

But it isn't like your case.

I think you mean the `n` is increased and decreased (same as mutating the list) on different threads. This isn't a **deadlock**, but **threadsafety** problem.

Even if you put a lock into it, you don't get a deadlock there.

```
object lockObj = new object();

 var up = new Thread(() =>
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
     {
         lock(lockObj)
         {
             n++;
             temp.Add(i);                   
         }
     }
 });

 var down = new Thread(() => 
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
     {
         lock(lockObj)
         {
             n--;
             try
             {
                 temp.Remove(0);
             }
             catch 
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("No item {0} to remove", i);
             }
         }
     }
});
```

But this will slowdown the process very much.

Comment: ...thank to much for your comment. But without lock(lockObj)..code is still working well and I want to understand why..And how to reproduce system hang up with thread without lock..