# Does this nested locking cause deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

Method1 and Method2 are public methods. Both the methods are required to take in two locks in the same order. Am sure acquiring locks in the same order will not end up in deadlock.
Are the locks in `Common()` unnecessary?

```
public void Method1()
{
    lock(LockObjA)
    lock(LockObjB)
    {
        //DoSomething
        Common();
    }
}

public void Method2()
{
    lock(LockObjA)
    lock(LockObjB)
    {
        //DoSomething else
        Common();
    }
}

private void Common()
{
    lock(LockObjA)
    lock(LockObjB)
    {
        //DoSomething else
    }
}
```

Comment: @L.B but C# locks are reentrant see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4846010/3165552). If they are reentrant and the ordering is everywhere the same they should not raise the chance for a deadlock. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @isi I thought the order of locks were different (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064296/is-deadlock-possible-when-locking-one-global-object-in-asp-net-mvc-application)). Forget my comments...

Comment: I have edited my post to conform the qestion edit, leave a comment if there's still something unclear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a better reference on the rush but i can remember well my Operating System course with resource locking where the professor stated that always acquiring the resources in the same order doesn't raise the chances for deadlocks to happen.

[always acquiring resources in same order](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK07-J.+Avoid+deadlock+by+requesting+and+releasing+locks+in+the+same+order)

Edit: Found [a stackoverflow question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951286/3165552) but still no article to this specific deadlock prevention mechanism...

Since c# locks are reentrant it should not do more harm when using your code.

**Back to your qeustion**

If all methods are private you have a really small scope within your class to check the lock conditions. So on public API it would be better to decorate all methods which are changing mutable state with locks. Even if that means that they might reenter on the same lock twice. In private API you can decide wether appropriate.

**Edit: After Qestion Edit**

If the three methods you have are the only one you have in your scope, or that three methods are the only critical ones (modifying/accessing mutable state). And since you can see nothing more to happen which can break the locking.

Then the answer is YES!  In method `Common` the locking is not neccessary.

**Note: Decorating methods**

By decoration i mean decoration in the sense of the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Which means execute code before and after some piece of code. In this case i mean the code inside a method. In java there exist a `synchronized` key word which allows to use a short hand to decorate the code inside the method conveniently with a synchronized block using the enclosing instance object. [This is called a synchronized method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: How do you mean "decorate all methods which are changing mutable state with locks" ? I'm not aware that C# allows you to "lock" methods, are you perhaps thinking of Java's synchronized keyword? (Or have I misunderstood, and you are just saying that the second set of locks are suitable if the methods are public?)

Comment: @VisualMelon added further explanations to my answer to avoid confusion ;) Thanks for the comment